# How to start a new navigation based application to work only in Ipad?

Tags: iphone

I want to create a new navigation based application that needs to be work with only i pad?How can i do that.when i start the navigation based iphone application and then try to upgrade the target to ipad.then there is two target files,and two main window xibs ,it is confusing me ,i need this application to be work only in ipad.i changed the device family to ipad?thsese are the steps done by me
1)created a new navigation based application in 3.2 with core data enabled.
2)upgraded the target to ipad(not universal only ipad)
3) changed the device family to ipad.

But this will give me two targets and two set of zib files,what to do?

is it enough? can anybody give the exact steps in achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, change the `Targeted Device Family` to iPad is enough.

If you still not feeling comfortable with the iPhone's files (main window xib for example), you can just delete them.

Comment: shall i delete the iphone xib files.and can u tell why two targets r coming there?totally confused.i just done this steps    1)created a new navigation based application in 3.2 with core data enabled.2)upgraded the target to ipad(not universal only ipad)3) changed the device family to ipad.But this will give me two targets and two set of zib files,what to do?

Comment: It depends on your Xcode version which you used to create your project. I am not sure why there are two targets (BTW, what're their names given by Xcode?)

Comment: application  application-ipad

Comment: When you modify a iPhone project to iPad only project, Xcode will just add files which iPad required, but will not automatically remove the files iPhone required for you. So I guess maybe that's why you've got two targets and two set of xib files.

Comment: so my question is when some body trying to run this in iphone what willl happen?

Comment: You can just delete the iPhone target (which I believe is "application") and xib file set, that's totally OK. Or you can just ignore them, in case you want to support iPhone in someday. As long as you are using "application-ipad" which I believe the targeted device family is set to iPad, your App will run on iPad, only.

Comment: Normally, your App can't be installed into iPhone at all - neither via Xcode nor via App Store. But if some one did install it into an iPhone (jailbreak users maybe), your App will not be able to run and will crash at the start up.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a single view template, then embed the initial view controller in a navigation controller. But you don't see many iPad native full screen navigation based apps. A split view is more usual.

Comment: Ya i am just trying to create the template only in 3.2

Comment: Well, I don't know why you are doing that, and I don't have 3.2 installed any more, so I can't give you steps for it, sorry.